# Mod_rewrite - remove question mark, not only query string

Tags: mod-rewrite, query-string

I need to redirect an url like mydomain.com/index.php to mydomain.com/

This sounds easy but the software framework also uses urls like mydomain.com/index.php? Those urls (with an single-added question mark) should not redirect to mydomain.com.

The problem cannot be solved whith using

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /? [L,R=301]
```

as this replaces/search for complete query strings such like foo=bar but not a single question mark.

How can I manage to redirect ONLY the index.php? I hope somone can help me out as I am an absolutely newbie with mod_rewrite and regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You just need this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ ^$ [R=301,QSA,L]
```

NB: this is for this case: the user in the browser types `mydomain.com/index.php` and is transparently redirected to `mydomain.com/` (and it's visible in the browser).

If you wanted the opposite this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index\.php [R=301,QSA,L]
```

This will do a redirect too (and in the browser, the URL will change from `mydomain.com/index.php` to `mydomain.com/`.

Please tell me if it works.

[update]

If you don't want URLs like `/index.php?` and URLs which have a query string, you just need this:

```
# if QUERY_STRING is empty...
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
# ... then try to apply the rule
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ ^$ [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately it is not working as required. When I use your first suggestion mydomain.com/index.php? will be also redirected to mydomain.com/? But that URL should not be redirected, only the pure mydomain.com/index.php should redirect to mydomain.com

Comment: Why? The **`?`** is just for query string. Maybe you don't want a redirect if there's a query string? Ok I've updated my answer for your need! Life is nice!